# What is does the pipe {'|'} mean in a configmap?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, configmap

My quest is basically:

What is does the pipe {'|'} mean in a configmap?
Code Sample:
Taken from: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: game-demo
data:
  # property-like keys; each key maps to a simple value
  player_initial_lives: "3"
  ui_properties_file_name: "user-interface.properties"

  # file-like keys
  game.properties: |   # <--- Here
    enemy.types=aliens,monsters
    player.maximum-lives=5    
  user-interface.properties: | # <--- Here
    color.good=purple
    color.bad=yellow
    allow.textmode=true
```

This seems a bit of trivial but what does it mean and what is its purpose.
Any special use cases.

Thank You for any clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a multiline string. See https://yaml-multiline.info/ for examples

Comment: I also had to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUPoq7Z0NRw