# What does - |- mean in yaml patch file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kind

In this example ([link](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/local-registry/)), it creates kind cluster with config file, which patch containerd. What does the `- |-` under the line of `containerdConfigPatches`  mean?

I found `- |`  in yaml indicates this is a patch field. But what does the `-` following `- |` mean?

```
# create a cluster with the local registry enabled in containerd
cat <<EOF | kind create cluster --config=-
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
containerdConfigPatches:
- |-
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."localhost:${reg_port}"]
    endpoint = ["http://${reg_name}:5000"]
EOF
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is does the pipe {'|'} mean in a configmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73082115/what-is-does-the-pipe-mean-in-a-configmap)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|-` introduces a YAML [block scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#81-block-scalar-styles), a way of writing a multi-line string.  The `|` means that newlines are preserved (`>` would fold the string into a single line), and the `-` means the new line at the end is removed.

```yaml
anywhere: |-
  This is a multi-line string.  The new
  line in the middle is preserved.
```

The `-`  at the start of the line (the space is important) is a YAML [block sequence](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#821-block-sequences) (list).  This is the same way other lists are presented; for example

```yaml
listOfStrings:
  - one
  - two
  - three
```

The `- |-` is nothing more than combining these two things: it is a list item whose value is a multi-line string.